# How to make a rectangle with long shadow in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a rectangle with long shadow like the image below using CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way:

```css
#rectangle {
     width: 150px;
     height: 250px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px black,
                 2px 2px black,
                 3px 3px black,
                 4px 4px black,
                 5px 5px black,
                 6px 6px black,
                 7px 7px black,
                 8px 8px black,
                 9px 9px black,
                 10px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there.

Have you tried anything yet?

You can use a div: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div and you can use box-shadow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow - but you might need many many box shadows to get that smooth edge. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

example using `linear-gradient`

```css
.box_volume {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #FFD700, #F0E68C);
  box-shadow:
  1px 0px rgb(320,163,35), 1px 1px rgb(192,167,7),
  2px 1px rgb(319,162,34), 2px 2px rgb(191,166,6),
  3px 2px rgb(318,161,33), 3px 3px rgb(190,165,5),
  4px 3px rgb(317,160,32), 4px 4px rgb(189,164,4),
  5px 4px rgb(316,159,31), 5px 5px rgb(188,163,3),
  6px 5px rgb(315,158,30), 6px 6px rgb(187,162,2),
  7px 6px rgb(314,157,29), 7px 7px rgb(186,161,1),
  8px 7px rgb(313,156,28), 8px 8px rgb(185,160,0),
  9px 8px rgb(312,155,27), 9px 9px rgb(184,159,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box_volume">
</div>
```